# Query node-exporter directly without going through prometheus server in Python

Tags: python, pandas, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have an architecture where I have prometheus server in one machine, and node exporters in others.
I want to be able to query node exporters directly without going through the Prometheus server, using Python and eventually put the data into a Pandas Dataframe.
I found [prometheus-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/prometheus-pandas/) but it allows to query the Prometheus server and not the node-exporter directly.

Comment: Node exporter exposes metrics in [textual format](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#comments-help-text-and-type-information). Request data from `http://myip-or-name:9100`, and simply parse response. Or is it not what you want?